# How to make common post or page for external links in wordpress website using php or any language

Tags: redirect, hyperlink, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

We help people. There are many people who want to promote their business or their content through social media and for that they create links of small WhatsApp groups and they share the links of such groups with us.

[links type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmGrC.jpg)

We put these links in posts on our website and many people come to our website and join their WhatsApp group through those links so that their content can reach more people, but we want that all the WhatsApp group links in our post should not be linked to any one.

Go through the common page. Currently, this happens that as soon as someone clicks on the link of a WhatsApp group, he gets redirected directly to the WhatsApp group.

We want that on clicking the link of all WhatsApp groups, first a page comes and then the When it is clicked, it will be redirected to WhatsApp. This common page will be created and the data that will appear on it will be taken from the current page.

This is a type of link redirection that will go through the common page.

This common page can either be a permanent page or a dynamically created page.

My site: [fancytextnames.com whatsapp group links](https://www.fancytextnames.com/).

I am not able to do this.